# UIImageView subclass not passing touches to controller subviews

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, uibutton, touches

When I add a `UIImageView` subclass (fullscreen) behind a couple of `UIButton` subclass instances, those buttons stop receiving the touches and don't function anymore. Nothing I have tried has worked to restore their connectivity to user touches.

I have tried:
a) Using a `UIImageView` subclass for the front view (that receives the touches) and making sure `setUserInteractionEnabled` is YES. Result: `UIButtons` are not responding when the `UIView` is present.

b) Explicitly passing the touches from the front view to the view controller in hopes that it will do the right thing. Result: `UIButtons` are not responding to the touches.

c) Calling the `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved` and `touchesEnded` methods directly on the button I want to interact with when any touch on the front `UIView` is received. Result: Strikingly, the buttons don't respond even when I am cramming the touch events down their throat.

d) Passing the touches from the front view to the `UIViewController`, and iterating over all subviews handing out the touches manually. I included a `touchesBegan` method showing how I tried to do this. When executed the loop is infinite, it never progresses past the first view (is of type `FrameUIView`).

I know this problem is likely the result of my lack of understanding of proper view hierarchy or the responder chain.

if I comment the last view created after the button, then the buttons work fine. Is there something special about `UIButtons` in this respect?

Here is the code.

I have a UIViewController subclass, in it:

```
    - (void)loadView {

        mainAppView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]; 
        self.view = mainAppView;

        frameImageView = [[FrameUIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        frameImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[[ThemeController sharedInstance] currentTheme] frameImageFilename]];
        [frameImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [mainAppView addSubview:frameImageView];

        zoomInButton = [[CustomUIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(controlsOriginX + zoomWidth + lightWidth, controlsOriginY, zoomWidth, controlsHeight)];
    [zoomInButton setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[zoomInButton titleLabel] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:28]];
    [zoomInButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doMyAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [zoomInButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelMyAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [mainAppView addSubview:zoomInButton];


        FrameFrontUIView *frameFrontImageView = [[FrameFrontUIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        frameFrontImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[[ThemeController sharedInstance] currentTheme] frameFrontImageFilename]];
        [frameFrontImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [mainAppView addSubview:frameFrontImageView];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
        NSLog(@"view is a %@", [view description]);
        [view touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}
```

Anyone with a tip on how to do this wins the internets and a cookie. Also accepting revolvers for russian roulette mayhem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the buttons without the image view behind them? Subclassing `UIButton` is not advisable. The way to instantiate `UIButtons` is with factory methods:

```
UIButton* myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

So my guess is that the `CustomUIButton` instances you have created are not properly set up.

Comment: Its definitely a good guess. I subclassed UIButton to solve a problem, namely that I want to be able to set the alpha of ONLY the background image, and not of the label or the rest of the button. I achieved this by making a subclassed button that draws two buttons on top of each other, with the top having the label and the actions, and the bottom an image button alpha set.

I will investigate them a little further, my next step was to do as you suggested and try a stock button.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a good approach. Try this: 
zoomInButton.imageView.alpha = 0.5;

Comment: Will do, thanks.

For the time being I shipped out on this problem by setUserInteraction = NO; This turns off the event and touch consumption by the imageview in the foreground, allowing the app to work properly.

As for how to enable interaction, but yet pass on those events/touches if not consumed....well I couldn't figure it out and I tried a ton of things.

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but I just ran into the same problem.

The solution I used is to create a container UIView, then add the UIImageView as a subview, then add the buttons, text boxes, etc. over that.  Seems to work well.

I don't really understand why this is an issue with using a UIImageView as the superview for buttons.